# Changing UIView's xib file and file owners code on UISegmented controller switch

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I am a highschool student and I am working on an application for world war one soldiers. Anyways, there is a `UIView` that contains a `UISegemented Controller` that when the users interacts will change a `UIView` Below.

So, an Overall `UIView` that contains a `UIView` and a `segmented controller` to change the contents of that smaller `UIView`.

I have it so that on the switch of the `Segmented Controller` does this

```
 switch value {
        case 0 : NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Profile", owner: self, options: nil)
        case 1 : NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Regiment", owner: self, options: nil)
        case 2 : NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Mapping", owner: self, options: nil)
}
```

The problem with this is that it just loads the `.xib` file and not their code. Their connections/events don't work and crash the program because it won't connect to their `.swift` file that is their `file owner`.

[image]

How do I `programmatically` set `.xib` corresponding `.swift` file.

I was hoping there would be something like this in xCode.

```
UIView.setParentCustomClass(class.swift) //Psuedo
```

Comment: Why programmatically? Have you set the file's owner in the xib file? This should solve your issue

Comment: This only works for the first UIView, then when you go to switch it crashes it because it looses the connection to the respective  xib classes code.